# How can I turn my react function to a react component?

Tags: reactjs

How can I turn this function into a react component?

```js
function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = React.useState([]);
  const maxNumber = 69;

  const onChange = (imageList, addUpdateIndex) => {
    setImages(imageList);
  };
}
```

Comment: A React component is a function actually https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html. In your case you'd need to return some jsx

Answer (score 0):

Return a JSX element from your function. it depends what you want to show. it can be something like this:

```
function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = React.useState([]);
  const maxNumber = 69;

  const onChange = (imageList, addUpdateIndex) => {
    setImages(imageList);
  };
  return (
    {images.map((image, index) => (
      <img src={image} key={index} /> 
    ))}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `images` state is a list of image sources...

```
function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = React.useState([]);
  const maxNumber = 69;

  const onChange = (imageList, addUpdateIndex) => {
    setImages(imageList);
  };

  return (
    <>
      { images.map(src => <img src={src} key={src} />) } // assuming `src` is unique
    </>
  )
}
```